# Draw all existing intersections

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, intersections

I have a set of arrows that intersect a circle and I want to highlight all intersections dynamically. I know that I can find those intersections via tikz' `name intersections` but I can't get it to work.

This is what I got so far:

[image: Rays and circle without intersections]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[shape=circle,draw] (eye) {};
 \draw[name path=circle1] (5,0) circle (1);
 \foreach \i in {-5, ..., 5} {
  \node[draw, inner sep=0, minimum height=0.25cm,minimum width=0.05cm] at (4,0.25 * \i) (pixel-\i) {};
  \draw[name path={ray-\i}, -latex,shorten >=-5cm] (eye) -- (pixel-\i);
  \fill[name intersections={of={ray-\i} and circle1,name=int,total=\t}]
      \foreach \s in {1,...,\t} (int-\s) coordinate [mark coordinate=red];
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

when I try to run this I get the error

> Package pgf Error: No shape named int-1 is known.

One problem is that there might not be any intersection for an arrow but I don't know how to make `\foreach` do nothing in this case.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently Tikz doesn't like when you extend the lines artificially using `shorten >=-5cm` so that's the problem. Your lines don't actually reach the circle, so there are no intersections.

This is solved by either placing the nodes *behind* the circle or drawing the lines independently from the nodes.

Here's a slightly different version of your code (which didn't result in your image anyways). I gave the nodes the name `pixel-\xi` because this one is the counter from 1 so the nodes have more proper names like `pixel-1` whereas using `\i`, you'd have something like `pixel--5` and then `pixel-5`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (eye) at (0,0) {};
\draw[name path=circle1] (5,0) circle (1cm);
\foreach \i [count=\xi, evaluate=\xi as \angle using int(12-(\xi*2))] in {-5,...,5}{%
\node[draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=.1cm,minimum width=.05cm] at (3.5,\i*.1) (pixel-\xi) {};
\draw[-latex,name path={ray\xi}] (eye) -- (\angle:7cm);
\fill[red,name intersections={of={ray\xi} and circle1, name=i, total=\t}]
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (1pt)};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While I suspected that, it does not solve the problem of arrows that "miss" the circle which I was asking specifically about.

Comment: @Nobody I see, however your code doesn't give me the result you present in your question. I'll present an alternative version with "missing" circles and edit the answer as soon as I can. :)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I thought I'd add the image as well after I had already pasted the code and played with it before posting it. I updated the code to reflect what the image is like. (Obviously, without the intersections)

Comment: @Nobody No problem! And thank you. I'll grab it then.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the calc library to extend lines.  Note that when `\t=0` the `\foreach` will still execute `\s=1`, hence the `\ifnum ... \fi` test.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[shape=circle,draw] (eye) {};
 \draw[name path=circle1] (5,0) circle (1);
 \foreach \i in {-5, ..., 5} {
  \node[draw, inner sep=0, minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.05cm] at (4,0.2 * \i) (pixel\i) {};
  \draw[name path={ray\i}, -latex] (eye) -- ($(eye)!2!(pixel\i)$);
  \fill[red,name intersections={of={ray\i} and circle1,name=int,total=\t}]
    \ifnum \t>0 \foreach \s in {1,...,\t} {(int-\s) circle (1pt)}
    \fi;
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: intersections]

Comment: I was afraid that I had to do exactly this. I'd hoped there was some syntax to make foreach do no iterations at all.

Comment: Nothing says a \foreach has to go from small to large.  In fact, \foreach \s-{1,...,0} should do both \s=1 and \s=0.

Answer (score 3):

As Alenanno explained, `TiKZ` doesn't like to use negatively extended paths for computing intersections. What can be done is use `calc` library to draw all rays with their exact angle. And as all of them intersect with right hand circle, the problem with missing intersection point disappear:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[shape=circle,draw] (eye) {};
 \draw[name path=circle1] (5,0) circle (1);
 \foreach \i in {-5, ..., 5} {
  \node[draw, inner sep=0, minimum height=0.1cm, minimum width=0.05cm] 
        at (4,0.1 * \i) (pixel-\i) {};
  \draw[name path={ray-\i}, -latex]
    let 
        \p1=($(pixel-\i)-(eye)$), \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}
    in
        (eye)--++(\n1:6.5cm);
  \fill[red, name intersections={of={ray-\i} and circle1, name=int, total=\t}]
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t} {(int-\s) circle(1pt)};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]